# Shortest way to cast a 2d int array into 2d double

Tags: java, casting

I have a method which only gets `double[][]` to which I would like to pass `int[][]`, is there a short way of doing this in java, something as simple as:

```
int [][] iArray = {
          { 1, 2, },
          { 5, 6, }
        };
double [][] dArray = (double[][]) iArray ; ???
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to cast your array is to iterate through each element and cast them one by one while re-inserting in your new `double[][]` array.

There is no shortcut.

Comment: Yeah. My sources are my own research on the subject. ;) Googling around will bring you to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not correct typing. int[] is a type and double[] is a type and they have no relation, so such assignments are not allowed. Therefore, there is no way to cast this.

You will have to copy the elements (you can assign an int to a double without casting).

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, is my code written in Java 8 worth being called **the shortcut**?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

// ...

/// Cast!
int[][] int2DArray = {{3, 1}, {3, 3, 7}, {}};
Object[] arrayOfUntypedArraies = Arrays.stream(int2DArray).map(intArray -> Arrays.stream(intArray).asDoubleStream().toArray()).toArray();
double[][] double2DArray = Arrays.copyOf(arrayOfUntypedArraies, arrayOfUntypedArraies.length, double[][].class);

/// Print!
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(int2DArray));
// [[1, 2], [5, 6, 7], []]
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(double2DArray));
// [[1.0, 2.0], [5.0, 6.0, 7.0], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast them, doubles are laid out different in memory than ints, this isn't a case of simply changing their name.

EDIT: Only if double was a super or subclass class of int then it *might* be possible.

Comment: That is not a very helpful answer. Even if the were laid out the same (i.e. both 32 bits), you still couldn't cast them. The Java type system simply does not allow it.

Comment: I guess what I trying to get across is that one isn't a subclass of the other, so casting doesn't make sense. The fact that they 32bits doesn't imply that they are laid out the same. But I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
    int[][] intarray = {{1, 2}, {5, 6}};

    double[][] doublearray = new double[intarray.length][intarray[0].length];

    for(int i = 0; i < intarray.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < intarray[0].length; j++)
            doublearray[i][j] = (double) intarray[i][j];
    }
```

Edit: as Andreas_D pointed out, this only works if all rows are of the same lenght, if you want variable lenght, you'll have to traverse the second for loop for a variable amount of columns.

Comment: You dont't really need to do the casting though, so you can omitt "(double)".
@Andreas; yes.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can cast a 1-dimensional array of `int`s into an array of `double`s :

```
double[] singleDimensionDoubleArray = 
        Arrays.stream(singleDimensionIntArray).asDoubleStream().toArray()
```

I therefore wrote what I assumed would be a faster version by looping over the rows:

```
int[][] iArray = {
    {1, 2,},
    {5, 6,}
};

double[][] dArray = new double[iArray.length][];
for (int row = 0; row < iArray.length; row++) {
    dArray[row] = Arrays.stream(iArray[row]).asDoubleStream().toArray();
}
```

I was just about to post this answer but thought I'd post some metrics about how much faster it was that naively looping over every element. It turns out it was around **10x slower**! I tested it with a 10000x1000 array of zeroes. I suppose it's the extra object creation that causes the slowdown.

Unless someone else can prove otherwise, I think the simplest solution is actually the fastest:

```
for (int row = 0; row < iArray.length; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < iArray[0].length; column++) {
        dArray[row][column] = (double) iArray[row][column];
    }
}
```