# casting a Java array

Tags: java, arrays, casting

i'm looking to cast an `int` array to a `double` one.

so, when i have

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

i want to use `arr`, say pass it as a `double[]` param 
to a method.

what's the best way of doing this?

the cast

```
(double[])arr
```

doesn't work.

i can iterate thru `arr`:

```
double[] dblA = new double[arr.length];
int ind=0; 
for (int x:arr)
    dblA[ind++]=x;   // (double)x;
```

is there a better way of doing this?

`System.arraycopy` isn't doing it-- doesn't work on arrays of two different primitive types.

Note: saw [Casting Object to Array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245533/casting-object-to-array-in-java) and some other discussions.

TIA.

Comment: Look here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710497/shortest-way-to-cast-a-2d-int-array-into-2d-double][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710497/shortest-way-to-cast-a-2d-int-array-into-2d-double

Comment: thx for the useful notes. 
C does these things. a bit discomforting that Java doesn't have t on arrays.

Comment: "C does these things"?  I don't know of any way you can do this in C without looping through the array and creating a new array by converting each integer to a double.  Did I miss something in C?  (If you're talking about STL algorithms in C++, I think there might be an equivalent in Java.)

Comment: @ajb System.arraycopy() doesn't have it. nothing in Arrays either. canèt think of anywhere else in the APIs whetre this can be.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question: where does C have anything like this?  There are some C++ functions where you could copy from one collection to another and provide a transformation function that operates on each element; but Java 8 has that ability too (using lambdas).

Comment: You can cast anything to anything in C. You'll get complete rubbish but you can cast it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using Java 7 or below there is no easy way around it, you will simply have to manually copy them over.

Using Java 8 you can do it somewhat easier (you do need to loop over the array of course) using streams like:

```
int[] intArray = {1, 2, 3};
double[] doubleArray = Arrays.stream(intArray)
    .mapToDouble(i -> i)
    .toArray();
```

This will first create an `IntStream`, then map it to a `DoubleStream` using the conversion `IntToDoubleFunction` which maps every `int i` do a corresponding `double i`. Lastly you collect it using `toArray`

Comment: You can use `asDoubleStream()` instead: `Arrays.stream(integerArray).asDoubleStream().toArray();`.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 there is elegant solution based on closure:

```
package com.java.se.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayCast {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        int[] inputArray = new int[]{23, 4, 5, 6, 89};
        double[] outputArray = new double[inputArray.length];
        Arrays.setAll(outputArray, inputArrayIndex -> (double) inputArray[inputArrayIndex]);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outputArray));

    }

}
```

Comment: What does the given `IntToDoubleFunction` do?

Comment: it converts each integer element and returns double value

Comment: _Which_ integer element?

Comment: sorry my mistake. Given IntToDoubleFunction function gets index of each element in int array and returnes converted to double

Comment: How is this more "elegant" than the OP's original loop?  It's more obscure, for sure, if you call that "elegant", and longer.

Comment: i don't find that code obscure. It's my personal opinion that closure based code is better